# How I can Add Start and end point in stacked bar chart in chart js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, highcharts, bar-chart

I need to add starting and ending points on stacked charts , is there any way we can add it.

[image: Click Here to view the image]

In The Given picture I need to start SaaS Quick Ratio from the 4 rather than 0 .

Answer (score 0):

Setting to [series.threshold](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.threshold) give you possibility to serve base to the column, in your case you can start column from 4 at yaxis.

```
 Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'column'
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Stacked column chart'
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas']
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'John',
    threshold: 4,
    data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2]
  }, {
    name: 'Jane',
    data: [2, 2, 3, 2, 1]
  }, {
    name: 'Joe',
    data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5]
  }]
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/f73zcu4t/